# "unexitable" GUI program

Tags: 14.04, gui, xserver

Is it possible to create a GUI application, where user can interact with it, but cannot switch to any other program (terminal, desktop, etc). Example of such applications would be something running on a public kiosk, where you will like the user to be able to use your application, but not mess around with the computer in any other way.

If this is not entirely possible, how much "harder" it can be made for the user to switch the application, and cause any potential damage to the system ?

PS: I am ok with running the program under a separate user account, chroot, etc if need be.

Comment: An example of this is the program `trigger-rally`, have a look at the code of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start the X server without a window manager (or a specially configured lightweight one) running nothing but your application. This example will use `xterm`, replace it with your application.

To do this, create the file `~/.xinitrc` and add something like this:

```
exec xterm
```

Now log in via TTY and enter the following comamnd:

```
startx
```

This should launch an X server with only `xterm` running.

You can also disable switching to TTY by adding the following to your `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
EndSection
```

Playing along these lines will land you where you want to be.

---

If you need a window manager, OpenBox might be a good choice since it is extremely configurable (you can remove all standard keyboard shortcuts, such as <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, etc.)

To use OpenBox, install it with `sudo apt-get install openbox` and put `exec openbox-session` in your `~/.xinitrc`, then add your application to `~/.config/openbox/autostart`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Kiosk mode](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/The-Kiosk-mode) for [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) that goes fullscreen after the program launches **BUT** for Linux it can be bypassed with `Alt-F4` key combination which is handled at system level. The library states that otherwise the program would be perceived as a potential virus:

> On Linux and Windows, users can still quit node-webkit by pressing keys like Alt + F4 and Control + Alt + Del, currently node-webkit does not block those keys be because it would make node-webkit behave like virus and be blocked by AV software.

Comment: Kudos @Tim for the quote.